# Duplicate metrics in prometheus?

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I am running the following Prometheus query:-

```
rate(container_cpu_user_seconds_total{image!="",instance="146.44.66.22:18080"}[5m])
```

and I am getting the following output :-

```
    {container_label_com_docker_compose_config_hash="24027ba5aca4c9f571f3dae01531efbc9f2f0158ea221d3f48d9bbd9c71a3b9f",container_label_com_docker_compose_container_number="1",container_label_com_docker_compose_oneoff="False",container_label_com_docker_compose_project="docker",container_label_com_docker_compose_service="tweetit",container_label_com_docker_compose_version="1.8.0",image="myImage",instance="146.44.66.22:18080",job="jmp",name="docker_tweetit_1"} 0.11122807017544115
{container_label_com_docker_compose_config_hash="24027ba5aca4c9f571f3dae01531efbc9f2f0158ea221d3f48d9bbd9c71a3b9f",container_label_com_docker_compose_container_number="1",container_label_com_docker_compose_oneoff="False",container_label_com_docker_compose_project="docker",container_label_com_docker_compose_service="tweetit",container_label_com_docker_compose_version="1.8.0",image="myImage",instance="146.44.66.22:18080",job="prod-job",name="docker_tweetit_1"}  0.11242105263158202
{container_label_com_docker_compose_config_hash="24027ba5aca4c9f571f3dae01531efbc9f2f0158ea221d3f48d9bbd9c71a3b9f",container_label_com_docker_compose_container_number="1",container_label_com_docker_compose_oneoff="False",container_label_com_docker_compose_project="docker",container_label_com_docker_compose_service="tweetit",container_label_com_docker_compose_version="1.8.0",image="myImage",instance="146.44.66.22:18080",job="trends",name="docker_tweetit_1"}    0.11249122807016726
{id="/docker/50b0033b372de336ad22c05e82fb6c689e95ce54ee687e01b8610b3d044b300a",image="exports,instance="146.44.66.22:18080",job="jmp",name="jmx"}    0.001719298245614067
{id="/docker/50b0033b372de336ad22c05e82fb6c689e95ce54ee687e01b8610b3d044b300a",image="exports,instance="146.44.66.22:18080",job="prod-job",name="jmx"} 0.0017543859649122805
{id="/docker/50b0033b372de336ad22c05e82fb6c689e95ce54ee687e01b8610b3d044b300a",image="exports,instance="146.44.66.22:18080",job="trends",name="jmx"}   0.001719298245614067
{id="/docker/ec8cc594235c0609a9f21404d86cec3d8b93844ecfc7b15170a74f1b55ed7d11",image="advisor,instance="146.44.66.22:18080",job="jmp",name="cadvisor-146.44.66.22"}    0.023052631578946346
{id="/docker/ec8cc594235c0609a9f21404d86cec3d8b93844ecfc7b15170a74f1b55ed7d11",image="advisor,instance="146.44.66.22:18080",job="prod-job",name="cadvisor-146.44.66.22"} 0.02308771929824536
{id="/docker/ec8cc594235c0609a9f21404d86cec3d8b93844ecfc7b15170a74f1b55ed7d11",image="advisor,instance="146.44.66.22:18080",job="trends",name="cadvisor-146.44.66.22"}
```

I am trying to display these in a grafana dashboard but i do not want the duplicates. How can i adjust the query so that i do not get the duplicates? Any help will be appreciated. :)

[image]

Comment: I do not see duplicates, because every line has different labels. You need to better specify what the duplicates are for you.

Comment: @svenwltr Thank you for looking into it. I want to display based on the {{name}} but on grafana i get duplicate names on metrics. I am adding the screenshot above.

Comment: @svenwltr I would like to display the metrics only once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the question is focus on how to adjust the query to have just 1 line...

As mentioned before, you basically have 3 jobs that scrape the information...

If you just want to see the information for one job, just add it in the query, for example:

```
rate(container_cpu_user_seconds_total{image!="",instance="146.44.66.22:18080",job="prod-job"}[5m])
```

This should bring you just the information for `prod-job`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have an issue with the scrape config of Prometheus. You can see that from the `job` label. It looks like there are three entries that scrape the **same** exporter instances.

Each entry in the config looks somewhat like:

```yaml
- job_name: jmp
  ...
```

```yaml
- job_name: prod-job
  ...
```

```yaml
- job_name: trends
  ...
```

It is hard to tell what exactly is wrong there without seeing it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no duplicate, you got 3 different metrics. If you want to specify each metric with job name, type `{{job}} - {{name}}` instead of `{{name}}` on legend input box. Otherwise you can add additional dimension into the query like `job="jmp"`